# Как добавить adMob SDK в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Как подключить SDK admob в среде разработки android studio?

Comment: вы пробовали по официальному гайду делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Идём в гугл.
2. Вбиваем туда

   > [android admob integration gradle](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20admob%20integration%20gradle)
3. Переходим по первой [ссылке](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start), коя является документацией по вашему вопросу.
4. Видим, что надо в `build.gradle` добавить нужную зависимость-библиотеку:

   ```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
   ```